# ProgressBar.js joining elements toghether

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rLRU.png)I'm trying to echo some products that the user owns.
I'm echoing it from the database via PHP.
Here is the relevant code:
The div I'm echoing into:

```
<div class="your-courses">
    <?php
        echo getUserCourses($_SESSION["id"]);
    ?>
</div>
```

getUserCourses basicly just taking the courses the user owns from the db.
The echo himself:

```
function getUserCourses($user_id) {
    include '../Backend/Config.php';
    include 'get_course_data.php';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `user_courses` WHERE `user_id` = ?";
    $stmt = $link->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $progress = $row["progress"]/100;
        echo 
        "<div class='course-flex-item'>";
            echo getCourseData($row["course_id"]);
            echo " Progression:".$row["progress"].
            "<div class='right-container'>".
                "<div class='container'>".
                    "<script>
                    var container = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
                    var bar = new ProgressBar.Circle('.container', {
                    strokeWidth: 6,
                    easing: 'easeInOut',
                    duration: 1400,
                    color: '#FFEA82',
                    trailColor: '#eee',
                    trailWidth: 1,
                    svgStyle: null
                });

                    bar.animate(".$progress.");
                </script>".
      "
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>"."<div class='collapser'></div>";
    }
}
```

This is the product flex items, and the progressbar.js script.
The relevant css:

```
.container {
    width: 7vw!important;
    margin-top: 5vw;
    padding-top: 50%;
}

.your-courses {
    height: 200vh;
    width: 60vw;
    margin : 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10%;
    border: black 1px solid;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-direction: column;

}

.course-flex-item {
    position: relative!important;
    border: black 1px solid;
    margin-top: 10vh;
    width:80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 10%; 
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.right-container {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    border: chartreuse 1px solid;
    height: 100%;
    width: 30%;
    padding-top: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

This is what it's outputting right now :
[image]

If anybody needs more data or files, comment.

Comment: What happens if you make your .container this: `.container {
position: relative;
}` I'm having a little trouble doing some confirming this because of the php so if you could share with me what doing this does possibly in a screenshot I might be able to help more.

Comment: it didn't change anything, ill add screenshot to the question @John

Comment: Anybody can help?